# Error invalid type (list) for variable

Tags: r

вот так функция работает

```
lm(mpg ~ disp, mtcars)
```

теперь мне надо обратиться к этим же столбцам по их номеру пишу

```
lm(mtcars[1]~ mtcars[3], mtcars)
```

выдает ошибку Error invalid type (list) for variable.

Как правильно сделать запрос?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7742301/4827341

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор `[` для класса `data.frame` возвращает список (`list`). Чтобы получить атомарный вектор, используйте оператор `[[`.